# How do I tell gradle NOT to build sources.jar and javadoc.jar?

Tags: gradle, jar

I have very simple build.properties that builds a jar, plus sources.jat=r plus javadoc.jar

I do not want the last two, and it slows down the build.

How do I tell gradle NOT to build sources.jar and javadoc.jar?

```
buildscript {

}

group 'com.premierinc.gporev'
version '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

jar {
    baseName = 'gporev-pentaho'
}


jar {
    into 'resources', {
        from 'resources'
    }
}

// added so Bamboo can extract the GAV variables
// and pass them on
task ('createPom')  {
    doLast {
        pom {}.writeTo("pom.xml")
    }
}

clean.doLast { file("pom.xml").delete() }
build.finalizedBy createPom
```

Comment: What do you mean by "simple build.properties"? The Gradle build process gets defined by a `build.gradle` script. Please add the content of the files relevant to your question.

Comment: added build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Options

1. Don't add the `javadocJar` or `sourcesJar` tasks to the gradle model in the first place
2. Disable the task (maybe based on some property)

.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
task javadocJar(type:Jar) { ... }
task sourcesJar(type:Jar) { ... }
if (someMagicFlag) {
    javadocJar.enabled = false
    sourcesJar.enabled = false
}
```

Comment: 1) I didn't 2) "Could not get unknown property 'javadocJar' for root project "

Comment: 1) somewhere in your build, either you, or one of your plugins did. 2) the task is probably called something else, try `gradle tasks`

Comment: `subprojects { javadocJar.enabled = false }` perhaps?